# Get last image when drawn using touchmove event in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing image on canvas onload and giving **ontouchmove** event to drawn image. Issue i am facing is when image is moved in canvas, multiple instances of image are getting drawn which is correct according to functionality but i want only last instance ?

```
    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;
    var y1 = 0;
    var y2 = 0;
    var imagesLoaded = 0;
    var img = '';
    var img1 = '';
    var img2 = '';
    var img3 = '';
    var img4 = '';
    var img5 = '';
    var img6 = '';
    var context = '';
    var canvas;
    function initImg() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('final');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img = loadImage('images/img01_res.jpg', main);
    img1 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img01.png', main);
    img2 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img02.png', main);
    img3 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img03.png', main);
    img4 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img04.png', main);
    img5 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img05.png', main);
    img6 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img06.png', main);
    img7 = loadImage(hidden, main);

    function main() {
        imagesLoaded += 1;
        if (imagesLoaded == 8) {
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            context.drawImage(img1, 22, 0);
            context.drawImage(img2, 68, 0);
            context.drawImage(img3, 114, 0);
            context.drawImage(img4, 160, 0);
            context.drawImage(img5, 207, 0);
            context.drawImage(img6, 253, 0);
            context.drawImage(img7, 48, 72);
            var d = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
    }
}

    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;
    var y1 = 0;
    var y2 = 0;
    var imagesLoaded = 0;
    var img = '';
    var img1 = '';
    var img2 = '';
    var img3 = '';
    var img4 = '';
    var img5 = '';
    var img6 = '';
    var context = '';
    var canvas;
    function initImg() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('final');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img = loadImage('images/img01_res.jpg', main);
    img1 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img01.png', main);
    img2 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img02.png', main);
    img3 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img03.png', main);
    img4 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img04.png', main);
    img5 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img05.png', main);
    img6 = loadImage('images/color_animation_img06.png', main);
    img7 = loadImage(hidden, main);

    function main() {
        imagesLoaded += 1;
        if (imagesLoaded == 8) {
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            context.drawImage(img1, 22, 0);
            context.drawImage(img2, 68, 0);
            context.drawImage(img3, 114, 0);
            context.drawImage(img4, 160, 0);
            context.drawImage(img5, 207, 0);
            context.drawImage(img6, 253, 0);
            context.drawImage(img7, 48, 72);
            var d = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
    }
}


function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    return img;
}
function onTouchstart(id, event) {
    try {
        x1 = event.touches[0].pageX;
        y1 = event.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    catch (error) {
        try {
            x1 = event.clientX;
            y1 = event.clientY;
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
    try {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    }
    function onTouchmove(id, event) {
    try {
        x2 = event.touches[0].pageX;
        y2 = event.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    catch (error) {
        try {
            x2 = event.clientX;
            y2 = event.clientY;
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
    try {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    context.drawImage(img1, x2, y2);
}


function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    return img;
}
function onTouchstart(id, event) {
    try {
        x1 = event.touches[0].pageX;
        y1 = event.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    catch (error) {
        try {
            x1 = event.clientX;
            y1 = event.clientY;
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
    try {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}
function onTouchmove(id, event) {
    try {
        x2 = event.touches[0].pageX;
        y2 = event.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    catch (error) {
        try {
            x2 = event.clientX;
            y2 = event.clientY;
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
    try {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    context.drawImage(img1, x2, y2);
}
```

Comment: Why not prepare a fiddle with the essential code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ClearRect** property.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var clear=context.clearRect(0, 0,width,height);
    var save=context.save();

    clear;
    //Your drawing code
    save;
```

Canvas draws and redraws at a very fast rate and thats what creates animation.Since you are not clearing your canvas and then saving it,you get series of images in a single frame,Thats what troubling you.Try this in your code and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre:plz put your code in the Question so that I can find the exact problem.

Comment: @ mr-jj,I have provided my code here. Kindly review and provide me solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre:did you try the solution provided earlier??

Comment: Sorry, but this code won't work and there is no reason to use save in this um.. context.

Comment: @RayonDabre:what exactly are you trying to achieve??Be more elaborative so that people can come up with more accurate solutions.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware:the thing is rayon just updated his question a little while earlier.So the previous question wasn't that expressive.Now anybody can analyse whats working and whats not.

Comment: @RayonDabre:I am finding it difficult to understand what exactly your code needs.can you brief me about the project and what all problems you are facing

Comment: @ mr jj ,I had tried the solution you have provided but its clearing the entire canvas and i dont want that to happent coz i have drawn many images on that canvas which i want to be persistent.

Comment: @RayonDabre:redraw after clearing.so that your images come back again.The thing is rate of clearing and redrawing is ultrafast.So don't worry ,your persistency wont be affected.Good luck with your project.